# Boolean Indexing to assign value on Multi Column DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a multi-column DataFrame, with dates as index, tickers as first level columns and different fields as second level columns:

```
df
   stock1                stock2                stock3       
   X1     X2     Y       X1     X2     Y       X1    X2     Y
0  True   False  NaN     False  False  NaN     True  False  NaN
1  False  True   NaN     True   False  NaN     True  False  NaN
3  False  False  NaN     True   False  NaN     False True   NaN
4  True   False  NaN     False  True   NaN     True  False  NaN
```

I want to use the levels X1 and X2 as a boolean array and set Y to 1 whenever X1 is True, and to -1 when X2 is True. When both are False, the NaN value is unchanged.

I have tried to use `pd.IndexSlice` to get a view of X1 and X2: `df.loc[:, idx[:, 'X1']]` returns the correct boolean array but then I did not succeed to use it to assign values.

Using something like

```
df.loc[:, idx[:, 'Y']] = (df.loc[:, idx[:, 'X1']] * 1).values
```

does not work since the `False` values will assign 0 where I want `NaN`.

Comment: Can you provide code to reproduce the input?

Answer (score 2):

I like @AndreyKesely method better, but you can reshape the dataframe, then assign values based on condition and reshape back to original structure like this:

```
dfs = df.stack(0)
dfs['Y'] = np.where(dfs['X1'],1,-1)
dfs['Y'] = dfs['Y'].where(dfs[['X1','X2']].any(axis=1))
df_out = dfs.unstack(-1).swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  stock1             stock2             stock3            
      X1     X2    Y     X1     X2    Y     X1     X2    Y
0                                                         
0   True  False  1.0  False  False  NaN   True  False  1.0
1  False   True -1.0   True  False  1.0   True  False  1.0
3  False  False  NaN   True  False  1.0  False   True -1.0
4   True  False  1.0  False   True -1.0   True  False  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
for c in df.columns.get_level_values(0).unique():
    mask = df.loc[:, [(c, "X1"), (c, "X2")]].any(axis=1)
    df.loc[mask, (c, "Y")] = np.where(df.loc[mask, (c, "X1")], 1, -1)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  stock1             stock2             stock3            
      X1     X2    Y     X1     X2    Y     X1     X2    Y
0   True  False  1.0  False  False  NaN   True  False  1.0
1  False   True -1.0   True  False  1.0   True  False  1.0
3  False  False  NaN   True  False  1.0  False   True -1.0
4   True  False  1.0  False   True -1.0   True  False  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Even though @ScottBoston's answer does not involve a loop (which I would prefer), I think yours is more flexible, as it is possible that I have additional X columns and a more complex logic. With your solution I can always make several masks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well:

```
(df.stack(level=0)
.assign(Y = lambda x: x[['X1','X2']].mul([1,2]).sum(axis=1)
.map({0:np.NaN,1:1,2:-1,3:0}))
.unstack()
.swaplevel(axis=1)
.sort_index(level=0,axis=1))
```